# map two table columns using pentaho Data integration

Tags: mapping, pentaho, editing, data-integration

I am using pentaho data integration in which I am able to get table columns but while editing I want the columns to save as edited but it giving some error able to save in .txt file and want to get as input for next transformation.

How to map two table columns using pentaho Data integration?

Comment: what error? provide more info.

Comment: how can we edit columns using pentaho??

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables using basic sql in the table input step itself or using merge join with their foreign key relations. keep this result is txn1. Now, create a job with two transformations. Use the output to above txn1 to another transformation.

Comment: As this is a very old question, it would be best if you can provide some sample codes and reference links in your answer that can help future users who find similar problem.